# Get pixel coordinates of a path

Tags: javascript, svg

A typical `path` element under `svg` will be like

```
<svg width="960" height="960">
<g transform="translate(480,480)">
<path style="fill:none; stroke:#000" 
    d="M69.963,-353.136
    L66.190,-341.705
    C62.417,-330.274,54.870,-307.412,46.957,-284.620
    C39.043,-261.828,30.762,-239.107,28.338,-191.600
    C25.915,-144.093,29.348,-71.801,1.420,-46.863
    C-26.507,-21.924,-85.794,-44.340,-128.969,-48.510
    C-172.144,-52.680,-199.207,-38.604,-234.999,-29.311
    C-270.791,-20.018,-315.311,-15.509,-337.572,-13.255
    L-359.832,-10.100">
</path></g></svg>
```

Now I need to get the coordinates of the pixels in the Bézier curve. I understand I can calculate the coordinates by the definition of Bézier curve. But are there any other more convenient ways (like some ready-made routines)?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it would be possible without using the formula that defines the bezier curve. There could be multiple x points for any y point and vice versa.

Comment: `path.getPointAtLength()`?

Comment: @JBux I don't understand why this kind of "multiple correspondence" would be an obstacle. I was thinking about getting a 2D array where each row is a 2D point on the curve.

Comment: @pawel thanks! I think the [SVGPathElement API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement) has provided me sufficient materials.